# How would I hide these dateset I don't want it to be printed out when I knit it to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown

[image: Just like in the picture, I don't want the dataset to show up]

It's so long to view if I knit it to the pdf.  So I'm trying to find a way to hide it.
How do I do it? Thanks

Comment: What _do_ you want to do with it if you're not printing it out? If you want to store it for later, simply start your line with something like `train_df_modified <- train_df %>%`. That way, you can use the result for calculations later, _and_ it won't automatically print to your pdf.

Answer (score 0):

in the {} section put the follow

`{r, echo=FALSE, results="hide"}`

Comment: But then, why have the chunk at all, since it doesn't carry any changes through to subsequent blocks? If you are going to hide it and it doesn't have any effect on subsequent code, you should just delete the chunk.

Comment: I don't have the OP's context as to why they would want to do that, so I am just answering the question as written

Comment: Thanks. It worked.  I did this because my instructor doesn't want many pages of data. He just wants to see the codes. LOL I know it's weird. He took points off on my previous assignment because of that.

Comment: if you found the answer useful, please accept it as the answer